# Git: master / develop / feature branch merge commits

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-branch

Here's the flow I'm following:

- `master` branch is always in sync with production
- `develop` branch is always the next version to be released
- `feature/feature-name` branch is the feature currently being developed.

After the feature is done, a pull request is raised from `feature/feature-name` into `develop` branch, then from `develop` branch into master branch. We do all these in github.

However, whenever there is a pull request on github, here's the merge branch created. Therefore, after `feature/feature-name` merged into `develop` branch, a merge commit is created; after a `develop branch` merged into `master branch`, another merge commit is created.

Therefore, in order to have 1 feature merged, I have to create 2 merge commits.

What is worse, now master branch and develop branch are no longer in sync, because master branch has 1 extra merge commit.

I got 2 questions:
1) am I following the right structure / practice?
2) how to avoid extra merge commits? Esp. how to keep the master branch do not create extra commit when fast-forwarding from develop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a few misconceptions in your question which I will attempt to resolve.  First, you said that

> Therefore, in order to have 1 feature merged, I have to create 2 merge commits.
>
> What is worse, now master branch and develop branch are no longer in sync, because master branch has 1 extra merge commit.

Yes, you are creating two merge commits, but you are only creating one commit in each branch (`develop` and `master`).  This is how merging in Git works; when you merge one branch into another, it creates a merge commit.

With regard to `master` and `develop` not being in sync, they might not have been in sync anyway if someone else merged a different feature into `develop` before you did.  From a functional point of view, assuming that no one else made changes to `master` since the previous sprint, when you merge `develop` into `master` then both branches should be functionally equivalent (although their histories might look different).

You asked this question:

> how to keep the master branch do not create extra commit when fast-forwarding from develop?

If your `develop` branch actually fast-forwards the `master` branch, then I don't consider you to be doing a Git merge.  However, if you *cannot* fast forward `master`, then one way to resolve this is to do a manual merge.  In this case, the merge commit is unavoidable.

If you really hate merge commits, then you should consider using rebasing instead.  Using `git rebase`, the source branch always "stays ahead" of the destination, allowing you to always fast-forward your commits into the destination.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think based on your desc, I can accept extra merge commit.

Comment: Check out rebasing if you really want to eliminate merge commits.  If I recall correctly, GitHub tries to enforce a merge-based workflow, which I never liked.

Comment: Yeah I know how rebasing works.. but also I want to enforce no push into master branch.. if fast-forward, that means I'll have to push into master branch directly.

Comment: This is the big dilemma and debate in the Git world.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right way it depends on you how you want to manage the branches. Some do it feature wise, some may do it module wise, some create separate branch for developers. But the key idea is to keep your local code in sync with master and develop branch, pull the updated code from the development branch more frequently.